# Spring bean name clash Hibernate/Proguard?

Tags: spring-data, maven-3, proguard

Consider a multi-module Java/Scala Maven application to obfuscate. It's using the classic Spring approach of Hibernate/JPA/Spring Data JPA/services/repositories/.... All using xml configuration files.

What has been done

- Keep intact class names mentioned in web.xml and Spring xml files.
- Keep intact the package names used in all **< context:component-scan.../ >** + bean name generator to guarantee unique bean names.
- Keep intact classes referenced by introspection.
- Don't use mixed case class names because Spring bean names are case-insensitive.

But whatever I try, I continue to clash bean names with what I think is Hibernate. An example of the error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate collection role mapping com.bar.project.Definition.d
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addCollection(Configuration.java:2739)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bind(CollectionBinder.java:561)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2084)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:895)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3625)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3579)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1381)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    ... 32 more
```

Proguard indeed made a class named 'd'. Which was duly renamed to something like 'BeanFFEECC' using the bean name generator.

```
class BeanNameGenerator extends DefaultBeanNameGenerator {
  override def generateBeanName(definition: BeanDefinition, registry: BeanDefinitionRegistry): String = {
    val id = Integer.toHexString(super.generateBeanName(definition, registry).hashCode).toUpperCase
    var proposedName = "Bean" + id
    while (registry.isBeanNameInUse(proposedName)) {
      proposedName += "0"
    }
    proposedName
  }
}
```

Unless I misunderstood the role of a Spring bean name generator, I would assume this should have fixed the name conflict. The very same error pops up when defining a class name dictionary for Proguard. To avoid it to generate one-letter class names.

Is there anybody who knows what problem I'm having here ?

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND IT !** Apparently Proguard will by default rename private fields. Which is common practise for entity classes. And since I've put the JPA annotations on the fields, you'll get a field named 'd' pretty frequently.

Adding the role to the configuration fixed that issue.

```
-keep class com.bar.model.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

Before that it was

```
-keep class com.bar.model.**
```